# How do you add an inline popup menu like Facebook's "hide story" menu?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, menu, popup

How can I create a simple popup menu like Facebook's "hide story" popup using jquery?  Is there a plugin that handles this functionality?

Here's an example:

[image: Facebook Popup menu]

**UPDATE**

I ended up adapting the following blog post to work: [Facebook Style CSS JQuery drop down menus](http://sammaye.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/facebook-style-css-jquery-drop-down-menus/)

Comment: +1 for the circle. -1 for not [drawing the circle free hand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775).

Comment: +1 for the advice.  Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All CSS with relative and absolute positioning.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/c36Gq/

---

Here is one with a little javascript added on: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/fRvs9/

Comment: @Tomm: Pity votes accumulate undue points. You aren't upvoting because it's a *good* answer but because you don't think it should be down voted. That means Neal got 10-2=8 points for a non-awful answer.

Comment: @Neal, I wasn't actually complaining that your answer was bad. I'm arguing against 'pity votes' on principle. :-)

Comment: I ended up adapting this solution: http://sammaye.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/facebook-style-css-jquery-drop-down-menus/ but since yours worked, with an example, I'm giving you credit.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#click_button").click(function(){
    $("<div/>", {style:'position:relative;background-color:navy;border:1px solid blue;width:150px;top:150px;'}).html('hello').appendTo('body')
});
```